# Drupal 7 form submission issues

Tags: php, drupal

Every time I add a `<form>` on my `basic_pages` The first time the form is submitted it bring me to an `about:page` blank in google chrome, I click back and re-submit and it works?

Has anyone else had this issue?

```
echo '<center>';
echo '<form action="members" method="POST"><div class="small primary btn" style="width:30%;"><input type="submit" value="Request to join On Krokodil" name="join"></div></form>';
echo '</center>';
```

Comment: These Drupal nodes aren't meant to create forms with own submission handling. I'd suggest you to create a custom module utilizing Form API for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

`drupal_get_form()`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7

instead of `<form>` tag.

As Drupal adds some unqiue tags to the form.
These tags help Drupal maintain consistency, security, validation and submission of the form smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

In now way, you should create the form in a node! Try webform module or build your own using the APIs